# Full Image slider

Tags: image, jquery-ui-slider

Hi i'm looking for an image slider to sit full background, ideally with a nice fade effect for this site. http://www.markcoffeyphotography.co.uk

I have one in my site at the moment but i'm not so happy with it and i'm looking at recoding the site more efficiently (hey its my first CSS, html site so give me a break).

I'm pretty new to coding so any help breaking what i need to do down to get the result would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may serve you well to venture into Wordpress.  There are *many* themes, plugins and lots of community help out there.  Additionally, check out [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework to get you started on clean HTML/CSS/JS.

[CodeDrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/) has a lot of jQuery (and other front-end) tools.

[This one looks nice too.](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/full-width-image-slider/)

[This one has the fade effect you're looking for.](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow)

Comment: Thank you, that's very much what i am looking for. I could'nt find one like that.